# How to get GUI access for a windows machine through ssh on a mac machine?

Tags: windows, ssh, automation, openssh

I am trying to implement an automation framework, where I want to run a script in python to launch windows .exe file(notepad for example) by using ssh from a mac machine.

I have already considered X11, openssh, freessh.

I am able to run the python script, but since I don't have GUI access in windows machine, I cannot see notepad being launched.

Also, export Display is not an option for windows.

I will really appreciate it, if someone can let me know how to implement this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Basically, we want to control windows gui from a client linux based machine through our scripts. We want to run a windows automation script on a guest virtual machine(windows os) from a host machine which has linux os.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/531787/starting-windows-gui-program-in-windows-through-cygwin-sshd-from-ssh-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

https://superuser.com/questions/531787/starting-windows-gui-program-in-windows-through-cygwin-sshd-from-ssh-client

Thanks for the answers!

Basically just intall Cygwin SSH and use screen to retrieve the GUI. Even an architecture based on Pyro/RPyC will help.

Comment: I later used simple socket based client server to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Parallels in OSX, another is to RDP (Windows version of SSH + VNC) into the server.

(I am not clear on exactly what your trying to acheive)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Basically, we want to control windows gui from a client linux based machine through our scripts. We want to run a windows automation script on a guest virtual machine(windows os) from a host machine which has linux.

Comment: Oh OK, what you need is an SSH server for Windows with RDP. I recommend using OpenSSH with CygWin and then combining that with Terminal Server Client (tsclient) to establish an RDP connection. Or just use VNC for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoHotkey for detecting if window exists. As far as I know you can use AutoHotkey from python. I cannot give exact links how to use AutoHotkey from python (I am not familiar with python) but there are plenty of links in google if you search "autohotkey python". Here is AutoHotkey code for detecting if window exists and in that case execute some code.

```
Loop
{
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;sets to window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match. So we can match Notepad Wintitle only with "Notepad". In that case we dont need Notepad exact Wintitle.
    IfWinExist, Notepad
    {
        ;Here should be any code that is executed if window exests.
    }
    Sleep, 1000 ; That command allows to check window every 1sec(1000 milliseconds). You can change that value or complitly remove that command.
}
```

*Always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website)! AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated!*

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution may be to use Jenkins. The setup steps are fairly straightforward:

- Install the [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) server on your Mac (it works fine on Linux as well).
- On your Windows VM, install Java and follow the Jenkins docs describing [how to set up a Windows node](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-HavemasterlaunchslaveagentonWindows).
- Once the Windows VM is connected to the Jenkins server, try creating a job in the Jenkins web UI, and see if the server can run it on the Windows VM.
- Once you have the job passing, you can launch it remotely from another script (say, from the Linux host you mentioned) using the Jenkins [remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). Or if a human is going to be launching the job remotely, they can simply use the web UI.

One important note:

Depending on the needs of your application under test, you may need to permanently leave a user logged in to the Windows machine (so that an interactive desktop is present), and make sure that the Jenkins agent is running in that user session. That sort of setup has worked fine for me in the past for testing GUI apps on Windows and reporting the results back to the Linux host.

The advantage to Jenkins is that it very nicely takes care of transferring the exit status and text output of the Windows app back to the Jenkins server, so that the server can notify you if anything goes wrong. That sort of system can be quite brittle and time-consuming to set up when not using Jenkins.

Comment: The only issue with jenkins might be when you connect the agent using ssh (which is more reliable way) I think, ssh channel will not have access to logged-in desktop session.